# Converting a List of Datetime Objects into a particular JSON format

Tags: c#, .net, json, datetime

I am using a particular Javascript Calendar tool to show days that have events on them. This calendar tool accepts data in the following format:

```
{
  "2019": {
    "7": {
      "2": [
        {}
      ],
      "13": [
        {}
      ],
      "27": [
        {}
      ]
    },
    "8": {
      "18": [
        {}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This doesn't look to be the typical date formatting for json. I have a list of Datetime objects in C# that I am trying to convert to this format, but have not been able to do so. Is there a way to construct a JSON object given the format above by using a type List in C#?

I have tried to construct the object by using .NET's JavascriptSerializer but this did not work. The format was incorrect.

Comment: Please show us your attempt and we'll help you get it working.

Comment: Which tool is it? What if there are multiple years? (It seems that the "enclosing" container for "Year" is not a collection)

Answer (score 0):

You should create a model representing what you want. Something like

```
public class Dates {
    public string Year {get; set;}
    public List<Months> Months {get; set;}
}

public class Months {
    public string Month {get; set;}
    public List<Day> Days {get; set;}
}

public class Days {
    public string Day { get; set; }
}
```

You can then create a list of Dates (root model above) and convert this to JSON using [Newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json).

(Sorry the code example is freehand, may need to adapt)

Answer (score 0):

There are probably better ways to do this with custom serializers, but you can use this as a starting point, using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq:

```
var random = new Random();
var dates = new List<DateTime>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   dates.Add(new DateTime(year: random.Next(2000, 2020), month: random.Next(1, 13), day: random.Next(1, 28)));
}

var json = new JObject();

foreach (var year in dates.GroupBy(d => d.Year).OrderBy(d => d.Key))
{
    JObject yearJSON = new JObject();
    foreach (var month in year.GroupBy(d=> d.Month).OrderBy(d => d.Key))
    {
       JObject monthJSON = new JObject();
       foreach (var day in month.Select(d=> d.Day).OrderBy(d => d))
       {
                monthJSON.Add(day.ToString(), new JArray(new JObject()));
       }

       yearJSON.Add(month.Key.ToString(), monthJSON);
   }

   json.Add(year.Key.ToString(), yearJSON);
}

Console.WriteLine(json.ToString());
```